# Gitlab refuses to create remote repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab

I have installed gitlab 6.5 using [this guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md).

I have run `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` and everything is green.

The problem is I can't clone or push stuff to the server with HTTP. I saw that the server is not creating a git repository in the folder, but only the wiki.git.

I can push and pull to the wiki.git?

Comment: seems like a permissions problem. have you check for the right permissions on the target folder?

Comment: The repositories folder is owned by git. I dont think that is the problem because, there is the wiki git to each project in the folder. If we say we have project test, there is a test.wiki.git but no test.git